# Get all the machines in sharepoint farm

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0, sharepoint-api

im writing really big script that will get a lot of info on the farm 
I want to make it dynamically so I want :
1.  Get all the database servers in the sharepoint farm 
2.  And I want to get all the sharepoint machines in farm

The problem is that with

> Get-SPServer

I get all the server together mixed up and I get the smtp server as well 
And with

> Get-SPDatabase | Select NormalizedDataSource

I get them multiple times

Please help

Comment: What order do you want to the objects from `Get-SPServer` to be in?

Comment: i dont care . do you know a way how to parse them ?

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is sort the objects returned by `Get-SPServer` and possibly filter some objects out as well. To sort by object properties you can use the `Sort-Ojbect` cmdlet and to filter out specific objects use the `Where-Object` cmdlet.

Answer (score 4):

If `Get-SPDatabase | Select NormalizedDataSource` returns all the databases, you can filter the results by using the `-Unique` switch:

```
Get-SPDatabase | Select NormalizedDataSource -unique
```

You can get all the SP application servers by filtering by role:

```
get-spserver | ? { $_.Role -eq "Application" }
```